# How create a second midi device?

Tags: devices, midi

I need create two or more MIDI devices.
Using the command "modprobe snd-virmidi", I create one midi device: "/dev/midi1". This device is connect in port 20. I can see in "aconnect -l" and put with another softs.

However, I need create anothers as: /dev/midi2, /dev/midi3, after that connect in other softs.

Answer (score 1):

The `snd-virmidi` module has the parameters `midi_devs` to specify the number of ports per card, and `enable` to get more cards.

The OSS API usually does not allow to have multiple devices (`/dev/midi*`) per card, so you should create more cards; run:

```
modprobe snd-virmidi enable=1,1,1,1,1 midi_devs=1,1,1,1,1
```

Or put the line

```
options snd-virmidi enable=1,1,1,1,1 midi_devs=1,1,1,1,1
```

into some .conf file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.